# Logic Behind Calculating Probability Using CDF

Tags: probability, cdf

In the book, Probability and Statistics for Engineers 9th Edition, the following CDF is provided along with two exercises and their solutions:

[image]

I understand the logic behind (a), however, what is the logic behind the solution to (b)?
Why would we not find the answer via F(3)-F(-1) = 1 - 7/27 = 20/27?

Comment: You'd have to tell us what convention is used for probability vs CDF